# how to define kendo model for nested object

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I need your help.

I'm in trouble with kendo ui. Now I need define nested kendo model. My server side give an object has other object.

f.e I have an ConstantItem object and this object has an attribute what is CostItem object. My server side returns to me ConstantItem Object and it include oid,lastUpdated,name,info,costItem.

Here is my kendo model.

```
    var ConstantItemModel = kendo.data.Model.define({

        id:"oid",
        fields:{
            oid:{
                editable:false,
                nullable:true,
                type:"string"
            },
            lastUpdated:{
                editable:false,
                nullable:true,
                type:"string"
            },
            amount:{
                editable:true,
                nullable:true,
                type:"number"
            },
            costItem:{
                defaultValue:{}
            }
        }
    });
```

as you see I need to define model for `costItem:{ defaultValue:{} }` here. I need a model here. Because I have to define some values for variables here.

Could you help me please? How solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Properties can be written in string and there you can use dot notation.

[Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/uNOke)

Comment: but not as a nested object, just a key with a dot in it.